# Increment Stroke color with some percentage in ellipse in xaml windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

[image: this is what i am trying to get]

I am trying to implement circular ring with stroke color upto only given percentage.
Please suggest some methods to do so.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeMiterLimit="30" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Hello"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean "up to only a given percentage"? Percentage of what? Transparency? Length?

Comment: Hello, I edited question,Added an image.

Comment: WinRT XAML Toolkit helped me in getting this.Thanks to all

Comment: you can probably try Arc Segment